Can differential probes be used with floating oscilloscopes, such as handheld/tablet scopes?
I am in the market for a differential probe (and possibly a handheld oscilloscope down the track for field work). One seller I came across has a warning for many of the probes that they sell saying "Only connect to a grounded (earthed) oscilloscope!" What is the technical reason for this? Is this common for differential probes?
I don't understand why a differential probe would not work with a floating oscilloscope (such as a handheld oscilloscope) - it's arguably not necessary to use one with it, but this reads like a warning that it might be hazardous to health or equipment to use this with a scope that does not have an earth connection.
Could someone draw a schematic of what is going on with the differential probe that would pose a hazard to use it with a handheld (floating) oscilloscope? The datasheet claims an input impedance of 10Mohms to ground. Is this not effectively isolated?


It needs USB-C for power.
If you need to use it floating then the power supply must have suitable isolation as well as the scope.

That's a good point, the seller page (and confirmed with the datasheet) claims that the maximum differential inputs are 300V when the probe is in 100:1 and 3000V when in 1000:1 mode, but the maximum input when grounded (earthed) is 1000V. Do you read this to mean that the probes are derated when powered by a non-isolated USB-C supply? i.e. you can measure a maximum 3000V differential when floating and a maximum of 1000V above earth when not isolated (I have no plans on approaching these voltages, I want to make sure I understand the datasheet properly, however).

They suggest plugging it into your oscilloscope USB port so it will be tied to the 'scope "ground".

If something were to arc over inside their product the 10MΩ could become something much lower and the scope could be energized at high voltage. Maybe they have protection that shunts higher voltages to ground.
CAT III 600V is supposed to be able to safely deal with a 6kV transient with a 2Ω source impedance. Is that arrangement actually capable of that?  I have doubts.

First, If your using a floating scope, the standard single-ended probes are already going to act as differential probes - your ground is already floating so you gain no advantage using an active differential probe. In fact, you will likely get worse performance using the active probe.
The reason for the waring is that the dielectric isolation is not guaranteed for safety between the input and output of the probe. Also, there is likely a lot of common-mode capacitance coupling the input to the output of the probe. What this means, especially at frequencies above DC, the input signal gets passed on to the floating scope. So if you are measuring high-voltage, the floating scope goes hot and is now a shock hazard.

Using a grounded 'scope controls the common mode voltage of the differential probe.
The other answers have coverered the safety aspects of having the 'scope and the device under test at different, potentially hazardous, voltages.
The differential probes will simply not work if the common mode voltage exceeds what their input amplifiers are designed to handle.
The most straightforward design for a differential probe would be a differential amplifier connected to the 'scope. This is unlikely to be able to handle common mode voltages larger than its supply voltage, and indeed it may be much less.
